# How would I check if a row of a Listbox is empty

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I'm trying to write an IF statement in VBA to determine if the first column along the row of a listbox is empty.
If the row is empty I want a message box to display. if the row is not empty then the row is saved to memory.

My code so far:

```
Private Sub RiskLogReviewListBox_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   With RiskLogReviewListBox
      If IsNull(Me.RiskLogReviewListBox, 0, 0) Then
         MsgBox "Item is not a Valid Entry"
      Else
         str1$ = .List(.ListIndex, 0)
         str2$ = .List(.ListIndex, 1)
         str3$ = .List(.ListIndex, 2)
         str4$ = .List(.ListIndex, 3)
         str5$ = .List(.ListIndex, 4)
         str6$ = .List(.ListIndex, 5)
         str7$ = .List(.ListIndex, 6)
         str8$ = .List(.ListIndex, 7)
         str9$ = .List(.ListIndex, 8)
         str10$ = .List(.ListIndex, 9)
   End With
   End If

   Unload Me

   RiskRecordEditForm.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Just check to see if the `Listindex` is equal to `-1` - that would tell you no items are selected. And keep in mind that `Empty` and `zero length string` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> determine if the first column along the row of a listbox is empty.

You can use `Len()` and `Trim()` to check if the first column along the row of a listbox is empty.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

'~~> Add sample data
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With RiskLogReviewListBox
        .AddItem
        .List(UBound(.List), 0) = "aa"
        .List(UBound(.List), 1) = "bb"

        .AddItem
        .List(UBound(.List), 0) = "cc"
        .List(UBound(.List), 1) = "" '<~~ Empty
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub RiskLogReviewListBox_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If RiskLogReviewListBox.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

    If Len(Trim(RiskLogReviewListBox.List(RiskLogReviewListBox.ListIndex, 1))) = 0 Then _
    MsgBox "First Column of selected row is empty"
End Sub
```

[image]

BTW you have your `End With` before the `End If`. Maybe a typo?

**NOTE**: I am considering the second column as the first column. If you meant the first column as in the first column then instead of `1` use `0`. For example `RiskLogReviewListBox.List(RiskLogReviewListBox.ListIndex, 0)`

```
Option Explicit

'~~> Add sample data
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With RiskLogReviewListBox
        .AddItem
        .List(UBound(.List), 0) = "aa"
        .List(UBound(.List), 1) = "bb"

        .AddItem
        .List(UBound(.List), 0) = "" '<~~ Empty
        .List(UBound(.List), 1) = "cc" 
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub RiskLogReviewListBox_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If RiskLogReviewListBox.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

    If Len(Trim(RiskLogReviewListBox.List(RiskLogReviewListBox.ListIndex, 0))) = 0 Then _
    MsgBox "First Column of selected row is empty"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this helped out a lot. I ended up altering a few things but they method of identifying if a row is populated or not is solid. cheers :)