# How to retrieve check of checkbox after clicking listbox_click() in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, listbox

What it would like to happen, when listbox is click it would retrieve the check of checkbox from the worksheet.

[image]

```vb
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()  
Dim say, lastrow As Long

TextBox15 = ListBox1.Column(0)
TextBox18 = ListBox1.Column(1)
TextBox1 = ListBox1.Column(2)
TextBox2 = ListBox1.Column(3)
TextBox19 = ListBox1.Column(4)
TextBox3 = ListBox1.Column(5)
TextBox24 = ListBox1.Column(6)
TextBox26 = ListBox1.Column(7)
TextBox5 = ListBox1.Column(8)
TextBox6 = ListBox1.Column(9)
TextBox7 = ListBox1.Column(10)
TextBox8 = ListBox1.Column(11)
TextBox23 = ListBox1.Column(12)
TextBox22 = ListBox1.Column(13)
TextBox4 = ListBox1.Column(14)
TextBox21 = ListBox1.Column(15)
TextBox20 = ListBox1.Column(16)
TextBox11 = ListBox1.Column(17)
TextBox12 = ListBox1.Column(18)
TextBox13 = ListBox1.Column(19)
TextBox14 = ListBox1.Column(20)
TextBox27 = ListBox1.Column(21)
TextBox28 = ListBox1.Column(22)
TextBox29 = ListBox1.Column(23)
TextBox25 = ListBox1.Column(24)
TextBox30 = ListBox1.Column(25)
TextBox31 = ListBox1.Column(26)
TextBox32 = ListBox1.Column(27)
TextBox33 = ListBox1.Column(28)
CheckBox1 = ListBox1.Column(29)
CheckBox2 = ListBox1.Column(30)
CheckBox3 = ListBox1.Column(31)
CheckBox4 = ListBox1.Column(32)
CheckBox5 = ListBox1.Column(33)
CheckBox6 = ListBox1.Column(34)
CheckBox7 = ListBox1.Column(35)
CheckBox8 = ListBox1.Column(36)
CheckBox9 = ListBox1.Column(37)
CheckBox10 = ListBox1.Column(38)
CheckBox11 = ListBox1.Column(39)
CheckBox12 = ListBox1.Column(40)
CheckBox13 = ListBox1.Column(41)

lastrow = Sheets("liste").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Set sonsati = Sheets("liste").Range("D2:D" & lastrow).Find(What:=TextBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
say = sonsati.Row
Sheets("liste").Range("A" & say & ":AD" & say).Select

CommandButton1.Enabled = False
CommandButton2.Enabled = True
CommandButton3.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

I tried the code above but I am always prompted with an error of

> "Run-time error '-2147024809', could not get the column property. Invalid argument.

Comment: Try something like `CheckBox1.Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 4)` for the 4th column. I am assuming that the listbox has values like -1 or 0 in the 4th column

Comment: See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738464/how-would-i-check-if-a-row-of-a-listbox-is-empty/59739045#59739045) on how to retrieve the value from a column of a multicolumn listbox

Comment: i tried but unfortunately i got a " could not get the List Property . Invalid argument

Comment: How did you add items to the listbox?

Comment: I have a command button for saving. Every entry that is saved will be save to the Worksheet lastrow, so listbox will just show what is  in the worksheet based on the textbox values and checkbox values . Checkbox values is the one that i got problem wit,h because checkbox values is True or False when you save that to the worksheet and when i would like to retreive the check of the checkbox when clicking it to the listbox that's the problem. Because maybe of the True or False and its always an invalid argument.

Comment: That is fine is it is saved as TRUE/FALSE. But in the Listobox, how does it show? TRUE/FALSE or -1/0 ?

Comment: in the listbox, it shows as True / False.

Comment: Ah ok. Posted an answer

Comment: Thank You Siddhart Rout, it works, i remove some of my code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

> in the listbox, it shows as True / False. – Crusin18 1 hour ago

You are strying to assign a `String` to a `Boolean`. Convert it to `Boolean` first and then try it. For example

```
CheckBox6.Value = CBool(ListBox1.Column(x))
```

`CBool("True")` will return Boolean `True` and `CBool("False")` will return Boolean `False`. If you think there can be spaces then try this

```
CheckBox6.Value = CBool(Trim(ListBox1.Column(x)))
```